# Adicionar evento de click em todos os botões com JavaScript puro, que seja equivalente ao feito no jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
function Listar(){
   var tbl = document.querySelector("#tblListar");
   tbl.innerHTML = 
    "<thead>"+
    "   <tr>"+
    "   <th>Código</th>"+
    "   <th>Nome</th>"+
    "   <th>Telefone</th>"+
    "   <th>Email</th>"+
    "   </tr>"+
    "</thead>"+
    "<tbody>"+
    "</tbody"
;

var tbody = tbl.querySelector("tbody");

for(var i in tbClientes){
    var cli = JSON.parse(tbClientes[i]);
    tbody.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
                            "<tr>"+
                                 "  <td>"+cli.Codigo+"</td>" + 
                                 "  <td>"+cli.Nome+"</td>" + 
                                 "  <td>"+cli.Telefone+"</td>" + 
                                 "  <td>"+cli.Email+"</td>" + 
                                 "  <td><button data-i='"+[i]+"' class='btnEditar'>Editar</button>"+
                                 "  <button data-i='"+[i]+"' class='btnExcluir'>Excluir</button></td>" + 
                             "</tr>");

 } 

}

  $("#tblListar").on("click", ".btnExcluir", function(){ 
    indice_selecionado = parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-i")); 
        alert(indice_selecionado);
       Listar();
  })
```

O código acima funciona normalmente, mas eu preciso fazer em JavaScript puro. 
Tentei algo como isto, mas não funcionou o evento de `click` nos botões:

```js
document.querySelector("#tblListar .btnExcluir").addEventListener("click", function(){
    indice_selecionado = parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-i")); 
    alert(indice_selecionado);
    Listar();
})
```

```html
<table id="tblListar">
<thead>
 <tr>
   <th>Código</th>
   <th>Nome</th> 
   <th>Telefone</th>
   <th>Email</th> 
 </tr>
</thead> 
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>01</td> 
   <td>cjshdvcnac</td> 
   <td>239923929</td> 
   <td>ajcjcsjcjcja</td> 
   <td><button data-i="0" class="btnEditar">Editar</button> 
   <button data-i="0" class="btnExcluir">Excluir</button> 
   </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>02</td> 
   <td>Ansc</td> 
   <td>239923929</td> 
   <td>ajcjcsjcjcja</td> 
   <td><button data-i="0" class="btnEditar">Editar</button> 
   <button data-i="0" class="btnExcluir">Excluir</button> 
   </td>
 </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Independente do que foi sugerido na resposta da pergunta, os códigos não são equivalentes, este seu código jQuery usa "delegação", logo o evento não é aplicado diretamente aos elementos com a classe `.btnExcluir`, o que ele faz é um "match" para detectar se o event.target em `#tblListar` obteve em um dos descendentes com a mesma classe que `.btnExcluir`. A diferença de setar o evento diretamente aos seus botões é que você poderia excluir e adicionar o botões dinamicamente sempre precisar adicionar os eventos novamente, é apenas um exemplo de uso. Mas pra reforçar a resposta não é equivalente.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento agora é equivalente. :D

Comment: @Sam agora é "quase", mas tem sim detalhes que diferenciam, com o registro de eventos, mas nem vou entrar em detalhes, porque o problema é mais na pergunta que na resposta, afinal é um caso de "helpdesk".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Acho que se ele nem tivesse tentado fazer seria um caso de helpdesk mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crie um `onclick` no `body` que irá pegar o click em qualquer elemento do `body` todo. Então você verifica se o elemento clicado possui a classe `.btnExcluir`:

```
document.body.onclick = function(e){
   if(~Array.from(e.target.classList).indexOf("btnExcluir")){
      var indice_selecionado = parseInt(e.target.dataset.i);
      alert(indice_selecionado);
      Listar();
   }
}
```

**Veja exemplo:**

```js
document.body.onclick = function(e){

   if(~Array.from(e.target.classList).indexOf("btnExcluir")){
      var indice_selecionado = parseInt(e.target.dataset.i);
      alert(indice_selecionado);
      Listar();
   }
   
}

function Listar(){}

// daqui pra baixo não é pra copiar.
// é apenas uma função para criar uma nova linha
// para ilustrar o funcionamento com elementos dinâmicos
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function(){
   
   document.querySelector("#tblListar tbody").innerHTML += '<tr>'
   +'<td>03</td> '
   +'<td>Ansc</td>' 
   +'<td>239923929</td> '
   +'<td>ajcjcsjcjcja</td> '
   +'<td>'
   +'<button data-i="3" class="outraclasse btnExcluir">Excluir</button> '
   +'</td></tr>';
   
}
```

```html
<table id="tblListar">
<thead>
 <tr>
   <th>Código</th>
   <th>Nome</th> 
   <th>Telefone</th>
   <th>Email</th> 
 </tr>
</thead> 
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>01</td> 
   <td>cjshdvcnac</td> 
   <td>239923929</td> 
   <td>ajcjcsjcjcja</td> 
   <td>
   <button data-i="0" class="btnExcluir">Excluir</button> 
   </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>02</td> 
   <td>Ansc</td> 
   <td>239923929</td> 
   <td>ajcjcsjcjcja</td> 
   <td>
   <button data-i="1" class="outraclasse btnExcluir">Excluir</button> 
   </td>
 </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
<button id="add">Adicionar nova linha</button>
```

Comment: Sam sempre presente. Rs

Comment: Sam, eu testei seu código e o evento click só funciona na primeira vez em que eu clico em um botão, ele mostra o alert e depois quando eu clico novamente não dispara mais o evento, o que pode ser?

Comment: @Sam No mesmo botão e nos outros também.

Comment: @Sam testei e deu o mesmo erro.

Comment: @Sam vou colocar a função Listar() na publicação

Comment: @LuanRodrigues Realmente havia um problema no código, mas já alterei da forma devida.